# What is the most efficient SQL query to find the max N values for every entities in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote these 2 queries, the first one is keeping duplicates and the second one is dropping them

Does anyone know a more efficient way to achieve this?

Queries are for MSSQL, returning the top 3 values

1-

```
SELECT TMP.entity_id, TMP.value
FROM(
    SELECT TAB.entity_id, LEAD(TAB.entity_id, 3, 0) OVER(ORDER BY TAB.entity_id, TAB.value) AS next_id, TAB.value
    FROM mytable TAB
) TMP
WHERE TMP.entity_id <> TMP.next_id
```

2-

```
SELECT TMP.entity_id, TMP.value
FROM(
    SELECT TMX.entity_id, LEAD(TMX.entity_id, 3, 0) OVER(ORDER BY TMX.entity_id, TMX.value) AS next_id, TMX.value
    FROM(
        SELECT TAB.entity_id, LEAD(TAB.entity_id, 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY TAB.entity_id, TAB.value) AS next_id, TAB.value, LEAD(TAB.value, 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY TAB.entity_id, TAB.value) AS next_value
        FROM mytable TAB
    ) TMX
    WHERE TMP.entity_id <> TMP.next_id OR TMX.value <> TMX.next_value
) TMP
WHERE TMP.entity_id <> TMP.next_id
```

Example:

Table:

```
entity_id   value
---------   -----
1           9
1           11
1           12
1           3
2           25
2           25
2           5
2           37
3           24
3           9
3           2
3           15
```

Result Query 1 (25 appears twice for entity_id 2):

```
entity_id   value
---------   -----
1           9
1           11
1           12
2           25
2           25
2           37
3           9
3           15
3           24
```

Result Query 2 (25 appears only once for entity_id 2):

```
entity_id   value
---------   -----
1           9
1           11
1           12
2           5
2           25
2           37
3           9
3           15
3           24
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make it clear what YOU mean by "keeping duplicates".

Comment: Hope my example helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` which will allow duplicates as follows:

```
select entity_id, value from
(select t.*, row_number() over (partition  by entity_id order by value desc)  as rn
from your_Table) where rn <= 3
```

You can use the `rank` to remove the duplicate as follows:

```
select distinct entity_id, value from
(select t.*, rank() over (partition  by entity_id order by value desc)  as rn
from your_Table) where rn <= 3
```